# How to extend div height as tall as the window allows?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I have a common page [structure](http://jsfiddle.net/wetjyLy3/3/) with fixed header and a sticky footer. But I can't get around how to extend the div heights to fill the full window area.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    header header header
</header>

<div id="page">
    <div id="left">side bar side bar</div>
    <div id="right">
    <p>I want to draw the brown dashed line all the way down to the footer even when the #right content is too little to fill the window.</p>
    <p>I know that I have to set height 100% on #right so that it stretches to fill the green box. But, the green box itself does not stretch to the bottom despite height 100% because the yellow box does not have explicit height defined.</p>
    <p>What can I do?</p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    footer footer footer
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, foot, header, div { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
p { margin-top: 0 }
html { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
header { position: fixed; background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 100%; }
footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; background-color: cyan; }
body {
    position:relative; /* container for footer */
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    min-height: 100%; /* not explicitly setting height to allow footer to be pushed downwards */
}
#page {
    padding: 60px 0 20px 0;
    border: 5px solid green;
    height: 100%; /* not working: how to extend page all the way to the bottom, min-height = fill the window? */
}
#page:after { content:""; display: block; clear:both; }
#left { float: left; width: 100px; }
#right {
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /* objective: to create vertical divider between #right and #left that extends to the footer */
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 5px dashed brown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning to make the divs always 0px away from the top and bottom of the window. You may need to play around with the values, but something like this should work:

```
#left { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 20%; }
#right { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 80%; }
```

Edit: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld0w17hv/2/) that shows how this could work.

Comment: The `width: 100%` with the `padding-left: 200px` would need `box-sizing: border-box` to work as intended.

Comment: is it still possible if I want to center the right and left? http://jsfiddle.net/wetjyLy3/3/

Comment: @Jake what do you mean, 'center' the right and left?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the reason why height 100% is not working its because body does not have a height at all, its height depends of the items inside body.

There is a work around for this

Apply the following to your styles.

```
html, html body {
    height: 100%;
}
#page { /* If #page is a lvl 1 child of body, this should work */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wetjyLy3/1/

Comment: I think this will cause the sticky footer not to stick anymore.

Comment: It depends how the sticky footer css and html is created, but both dom elements can be configured to work together. I know this because I have several sites with sticky footers and a content area of 100% in height

Comment: I just checked my solution against his jsFiddle and is working

Comment: If you make the text extend below the footer, you can see that the footer does not get pushed down.

Comment: You are right. His method for a sticky footer will not allow this to work properly.

Comment: Why do you need #page height to be 100%?

Comment: if what you want its a vertical line showing up all the way from top to bottom, I would suggest creating a background image 5x1 in size with the color you need and the just set this image to the body's background with repeat-y option on and just set the position. That's one way. If you want I could create some code for you and show you what I mean.